# TypeError: Can not convert a int32 into a Tensor or Operation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running the following on python 3.6:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = 2
y = 3
add_op = tf.add(x, y)
mul_op = tf.mul(x, y)
useless = tf.mul(x, add_op)
pow_op = tf.pow(add_op, mul_op)
with tf.Session() as sess:
      z, not_useless = sess.run([op3, useless])
```

and got this error:

```
   TypeError: Can not convert a int32 into a Tensor or Operation.
```

Comment: Is this referring to a specific line?

Comment: it must be about last line. the code is from page 41 of the following slide

https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs20si/2017/lectures/slides_01.pdf

Comment: ok found the problem! :)
with tf.Session() as sess:
           z, not_useless = sess.run([pow_op, useless])
           print(z)
           print(not_useless)

Comment: Alright then , so what are we using as `op3`?

Comment: the author mixed up op3 nad pow_op in her slide

Comment: Send a bug report and answer your own question?

Comment: sorry, I thought its my mistake in python coding . shall i delete the post?

Comment: While the slides are still online and wromg this may help someone else - but tell the author?

Comment: sure, will inform here.